# How can I parse and group incorrect JSON data in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, json

### **Solved my problem**

```
var allKeys = ["key","en","ar"];
for(var i=0;i<allKeys.length;i++) {
  for(j=0;j<jsonText.Sheet1.length;j++) { 
   console.log(allKeys[i] + ' - ' + jsonText.Sheet1[j][allKeys[i]]);
  }
}
```

[Running version](https://plnkr.co/edit/BN1cb9LGuC0uTkkKDhtT?p=preview)

Thanks @Aniket Sinha

---

How I can parse and then group incorrect JSON data?

**My *incorrect* JSON data;**

```
{
  "Sheet1": [
    {
      "key": "title",
      "en": "title",
      "ar": "arabic_title", //trailing comma here
    },
    {
      "key": "content",
      "en": "content",
      "ar": "arabic_content",  //trailing comma here
    }
  ]
}
```

**I want this result:**

key - title

key - content

en - title

en - content

ar - arabic_title

ar - arabic_content

Comment: What's the problem you're facing? Are you unable to fetch the values from  this JSON? Or do you want to group all the keys `key`, `en` and `ar` together?

Comment: Yeah! I want to group all the keys key, en and ar together.

Comment: @secret35 please check my answer

Comment: The JSON provided is still invalid. There can be no comma after the last value in an object literal. Please explain where you get this invalid formatted data from.

Comment: @trincot I convert excel to json. I use this lib : https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx/blob/master/README.md - this lib result data above

Comment: @lapuckire I read your answer because my library gives a result like this.

Comment: If that is indeed true, and you are not building the JSON yourself via calls to that library, then contact the author of the library and explain your issue. As long as the JSON is not correct, you cannot use JSON.parse.

Comment: Since this question has been marked as duplicate, I'm unable to answer it.  Check this plunk (https://plnkr.co/edit/BN1cb9LGuC0uTkkKDhtT?p=preview) for solution. Check console for output.

Comment: Regarding the JSON, it's invalid because of dangling comma after `"ar": "arabic_title",`. Read up on it here: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-comma-dangle

Comment: @AniketSinha thank you so much for reply, It's worked

Comment: @AniketSinha I updated json data but libs the last line adds a comma :(

Comment: It's unfortunate that the lib is generating trailing comma. In that case, hackish way is to remove all trailing commas using `replace`.

`JSON.parse(jsonText.replace(/,}/g,'}'))`, where `jsonText` is your string having trailing comma.

Plunk for reference: https://plnkr.co/edit/xgFDZgUt3TTOr8VdkySp?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

[JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```
var object = JSON.parse('{"Sheet1":[{"key":"title","en":"title","ar":"arabic_title"},{"key":"content","en":"content","ar":"arabic_content"}]}');
var key0 = object.Sheet1[0].key;
key0 == "title";
```

**ADDITION:**

Your JSON string is in bad format. There should by no comma after `"ar": "arabic_title"` and `"ar": "arabic_content"`.

Comment: Why are you assuming that JSON is passed as string?

Comment: the number of series and the keys may sound different. I want to do is combine them with the same key

Comment: me data is coming this way, and I don't have a chance to change

Comment: Then it's a problem of the other side, the JSON string is obviously in a wrong format.